# Passing multiple variable through a form

Tags: php, html

I have the following code, the variable 'name' and 'project' need to go to session variables on submit, in this case the submit happens through an 'onchange'event. The 'name' variable is POSTed but not the 'project' variable. Any ideas where my issue is?

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
<?php
$query = $conn->prepare("SELECT name, project FROM models.models where models.active = 'yes'");
$query->execute();
while($r = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){

echo "
<div class='swiper-slide'>
  <input type='image' src='models/thumbs/",$r->name,".jpg' id='name' name='name' value='",$r->name,"' onchange='this.form.submit();'/>
  <input type='hidden' value='",$r->project,"' name='project' />
</div>

";
}

?>
</form>
```

Comment: There is no obvious reason that code wouldn't work. Try doing some debugging. Does the generated HTML source code have the correct values in it? Does the data appear in the submitted data if you examine it with the Network tab of your browser's developer tools? What do you get if you examine the entire contents of the `$_POST` array (e.g. with `var_dump`)?

Comment: Your question is too broad. If you have two different questions, then don't bundle them together.

Comment: I'm using var_dump($_SESSION); the query is successful, but the project variable is not being posted.

Comment: I cleared the project variable using $_SESSION['project'] = ""; it is only setting one value (there are two values jake and john) only jake is assigned to the variable.

Comment: Can you please edit your post, adding all relevant code that would write to and read from `$_SESSION`? Are you thinking that the post data should appear there? perhaps there is code written to handle that.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
$query = $conn->prepare("SELECT name, project FROM models.models where models.active = 'yes'");

$query->execute();
while($r = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){

echo "
<div class='swiper-slide'>
  <input type='image' src='models/thumbs/",$r->name,".jpg' id='name' name='name[]' value='",$r->name,"' onchange='this.form.submit();'/>
  <input type='hidden' value='",$r->project,"' name='project' />
</div>

";

}

?>
```

How to access:

```
$names = $_POST['name'];

for($i=0;$i<count($names);$i++)
{
   echo $names[$i]."<br>";
}
```

Comment: There is no point in making `name` into an array. The question says that that bit works fine.  The problem is that `project` does not appear.

Comment: How about on his addition part @Quentin ?